# C++ - boost get question

Tags: c++, performance, boost, variant

Does someone know if the `boost::get` for the `boost::variant` is a *performance-consuming operation* or *not.*

Right now I am refactoring some old code in a *performance-critical part*, where "varianting" was implementing by containers for each possible types and corresponding `enum`.

Obviously, this is fast, but ugly and right now when I have to refactor the code so that it would work with **one more type**, I want to get rid of that old part of code and replace it with `boost::variant`.

*Also, I can't simple "profile both variants and compare" because this refactoring is a pain in the ass and would be pretty time consuming.*

So, if someone knows how does `boost::get<x>` performs comparing to generic `enum-based` type dispatching, I would appreciate if you share this knowledge.

*There is another variant of using `boost::variant<types>` with custom visitor (as described in `boost::variant` documentation) - may this be faster than `boost::get` in my case?*

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/variant/get.hpp

Comment: If a _custom_ operation were faster than their own, wouldn't they rather base their own implementation on the custom implementation??

Comment: Did you finally go for the `void*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could still write a simple test-application to compare the two, it doesn't have to be the production environment.

A colleague of mine had a similar problem to this one recently. In his scenario there where objects of different types, but he always knew beforehand which type he expected. Also his data-structure was huge, so memory was an issue. He solved the problem by using `void *` and `reinterpret_cast`. This prevents the memory-overhead of polymorphism and is very fast. You have to be absolutely sure of what you are doing though, otherwise things will explode.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, `get<>` is implemented using the internal visitor mechanism of the `boost::variant`. In turn, the visitor mechanism relies on `mpl` sequences, and it is executed step by step. That means at most *n* steps on an *n* type variant, but the loop (recursive call) is there. Again, as Space Cowboy suggests, a small performance test would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that it would take longer to access the last of the listed types than the first? A quick test shows that this doesn't seem to be the case. Are you sure the recursion isn't compile-time?

Comment: UncleBens: Looking at it twice, the search is unrolled to a given limit (that for what I've seen is the actual mpl list size limit, whatever is it). Then, the call is recursive. So yes, maybe up to 10 types or so there is no recursive call, but again, as you say, nothing better than a small test.